# There is no SDK with the name or path

Tags: iphone, sdk, radix

I know this question has already been asked quite a few times, I was looking for a more recent answer since the Xcode interface has changed since previous versions..

Basically my version of Xcode is 3.2.3 and can run iPhone 4.0 simulations. I did some work on it on another PC and know when I try to compile I get this error message:

error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphonesimulator4.1'

I tried changing my base to a lower iPhone device 3.2 but nothing.. Probably this just is a versions conflict but is there any way to work on this at home i.e on Xcode 3.2.3?

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: try clicking on info button on your target and check the build section. May be you will have to change the build for target option or something like that in the given list

Answer (score 0):

Click "Info" on your project, and going to the Build Settings :
In your supported platforms you should have "iphonesimulator iphoneos".
Check "Base SDK", should be "Latest iOS"
Check "iOS deployment target", your should have 4.0 if I understand what you said.